# Dynamic Textbox in row and Column wise using javascript.i try to sum each row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created Dynamic Textbox row and column wise.

Now I want to sum of each quantity in row wise and the total value display in total textbox.

Comment: So what a problem? Give me a code.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: <script> $(document).ready(function (){$("#divDyna").on("change", ".quantity", function () {    // <-- Only changed this line
  var sum = 0; $(".quantity").each(function () {  if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0)  {  sum += parseFloat(this.value); }  }); $('#total').val(sum); });});</script>

Comment: <input type="text1" name="n1" class="qty_total" id="total" required readonly="readonly" >

Comment: <script>
$('.quantity').blur(function (){var sum = 0;
$(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').each(function()   {  sum += Number($(this).val()); });
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.qty_total').val(sum); });
</script>

Comment: when i was using static textbox that time this coding is working proper

Comment: what are the issues in this coding